# Looking for a really dizzying boardgame

Tags: identify-this-game

Long ago, I think it was in the 1980s-1990s, I once played a game that really made me dizzy.

I think it was a game made by a German game maker. It was a 2 or 3 player game played on a round board, consisting of 6 concentric circles and connecting lines and spirals. The goal of the game  was to create certain combinations of stones, by which you could capture stones of your opponent.

Because you were constantly looking around circles and spirals, you just became dizzy, something you didn't notice while playing, but you noticed when you stood up...

I would like to buy this game , but I don't know the name.

Comment: There are 4 pages of spiral games on bgg. Maybe it is one of those: http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/160261/games-spirals/page/1?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a variant of circular chess. There is a 1993 board game under the name of Noble Celts that comes close to your description. (There are 8 concentric circles instead of 6.) Here's the board:

[image: Game Board]